# Problema al alinear imagen

Tags: html, html5

Necesito alinear una imagen para mi web, me sale en la izquierda, quiero centrarla pero no hallo la forma de solucionarlo, espero que podais ayudarme.

Código empleado "ADJUNTO IMAGEN"[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
:`<img src="images/pase2.png" class="align-center" style="align-content: center" />`

"La web es extensa por eso no he posteado todo el código".

Ha sido creada con HTML5 y CSS3 .

Comment: ¿Quieres centrar la imagen tanto vertical como horizontal?

Comment: claro,osea la imagen es un cuadrado como bien ves,el ancho y el alto estan bien a mi parecer se que puedo quitar un poco el alto y el ancho con las etiquetas width="" height="",lo que realmente quiero es centrarlo en la web,que no me quede inclinado a la izquierda,ya que queda visualmente feo

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo el siguiente código, es importante que el contenedor de la imagen tenga un ancho y alto definidos y que posea la propiedad `flex`:

```css
.contenedor{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* alineación horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* alineación vertical */
}
img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://www.taggedmx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/1-7.jpg">
</div>
```

Intenta el siguiente código si no quieres ponerlo en otro archivo CSS.

```
<div style="position:absolute;width: 100vw;height: 100vh;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
    <img src="https://www.taggedmx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/1-7.jpg" style="width:500px;height:500px">
</div>
```

Comment: ese css lo pongo en el main verdad?

Comment: @Krastez el código iría al lado de tu CSS.

Comment: perdona pero no entendí tu referéncia,te refieres a incluirlo en mi main.css o en que zona del html?

Comment: En el main estaría bien, lo importante es que el HTML pueda acceder a este código CSS.

Comment: vale,pues me dio error es decir,lo puse en el main y puse el codigo tal y como me lo adjuntastes y... mira el resul. ahora quedo mas pequeño y con una linea roja alrededor de la imagen (eso nome importa ciertamente) te enlazo imagen en imgur https://imgur.com/a/Fy0Tzl5

Comment: El borde rojo lo puse solo para mostrar la imagen centrada, puedes eliminarlo, he editado el código.

Comment: puse el css tal y como me lo pusistes ahi y el html y la imagen se me sigue quedando en la izquierda :\

Comment: Algo estás haciendo mal ¿Es posible que publiques tu código en un Snippet para revisarlo?

Comment: dame un segundo

Comment: no puedo pasar css y html porque son mas de 30000 caracteres xD hay algun otro metodo?

Comment: Usa codepen o jsfiddle.

Comment: contenedor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* alineación horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* alineación vertical */
}
img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;  
}

Comment: Mira muy bien como lo estás poniendo, no tiene el . la clase contenedor y las alineaciones están quedando comentadas.

Comment: amigo,lo he puesto todo exactamente copiado y nada sigue estando en la izq,lo que si me di cuenta es que si le quito el punto me lo lee como bueno el css no se porque pero igualmente el fallo sigue saliendo

Comment: Intenta poner el código solo en el HTML (elimina lo que hayas puesto en el CSS), he editado la pregunta para que lo veas.

Comment: Ahora si @jonathan-arias <3 mil gracias por la inmensa ayuda que me has aportado junto a los demás compañeros <333

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Krastez? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

**KIS** (KEEP IT SIMPLE) = "Que sea sencillo"

**Me parece que no hace falta explicar esto**

**CENTRO WEB**

```
img.class-name{

    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}

<img class="class-name" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51M0EmWDMPL._SL160_SL150_.jpg" />
```

**CENTRO ARRIBA COMO BLOQUE**

```
<style type="text/css">
img.center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
<img class="center" src ="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">

</div>
```

**OTRA MANERA COMO PÁRRAFO**

```
<p style="text-align:center; border:1px solid black"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"></p>
```

Comment: bonita zapatilla,voy a probarlo xD

Comment: amigo de la zapatilla,no sirve ese codigo,se superpone justo en el centro de la web no arriba en el centro xD

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer lo siguiente

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="tuimagen.jpg">
</div>
<style>
    .content img {
        margin : 0 auto;
    }
<style>
```

Comment: sigue igual a la izquierda

Comment: mandame tu codigo el html y css

Comment: Para jugar verticalmente con la pocision seria eficiente con el margin top!, Saludos

Comment: imposble pasar html completo y css a la vez +30k caracteres demasiado largo hay otro metodo?

Comment: Amigo no es necesario pasar todo el codigo esto seria irreverente, solo el fragmento donde insertas la imagen con el css